# Por qué mi araña creada en Scrapy con Python repite los datos

Tags: python, scraping, scrapy

Como dice el título estoy haciendo una araña, es la primera vez que hago algo como esto. hasta ahora mi araña ya puede seguir los enlaces y traerse el texto. Es una araña sencilla.

Pero el problema esta que me repite los datos cuando los exporto a un Json.

Mi duda es ¿Qué tengo mal? o ¿Por qué mi araña repite los datos? Estoy usando Python 3.8

```py
    import scrapy

    from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
    from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

    class WitsiSpider(CrawlSpider):
        name = 'witsi'
        allowed_domains = ['www.quotes.toscrape.com']
        start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com']
        base_url = 'http://quotes.toscrape.com'
     
        rules = (
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'page/'),callback = 'parse', follow=True ),
         )
        
        def parse(self, response):
            citas = response.xpath('//*[@class="quote"]')
            for cita in citas:
                texto = cita.xpath('.//span[@class="text"]/text()').extract_first()
                autor = cita.xpath('.//*[@class="author"]/text()').extract_first()
                palabras_claves = cita.xpath('.//*[@itemprop="keywords"]/@content').extract_first()
            
                yield{ 'Texto' : texto,
                       'Autor' : autor,
                       'Palabras Claves' : palabras_claves }
```

**La Salida por consola es esta**

```
2020-09-09 14:02:36 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 43886,
 'downloader/request_count': 153,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 153,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 217935,
 'downloader/response_count': 153,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 153,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 794,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 6.949397,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 9, 20, 2, 36, 813941),
 'item_scraped_count': 332,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 486,
 'log_count/INFO': 11,
 'request_depth_max': 11,
 'response_received_count': 153,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 153,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 153,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 153,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 153,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 9, 20, 2, 29, 864544)}
2020-09-09 14:02:36 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

y esta es la salidad de los datos

> {"Texto": "\u201cThere are only two ways to live your life. One is as though nothing is a miracle. The other is as though everything is a miracle.\u201d", "Autor": "Albert Einstein", "Palabras Claves": "inspirational,life,live,miracle,miracles"},
> {"Texto": "\u201cThere are only two ways to live your life. One is as though nothing is a miracle. The other is as though everything is a miracle.\u201d", "Autor": "Albert Einstein", "Palabras Claves": "inspirational,life,live,miracle,miracles"},
> {"Texto": "\u201cThere are only two ways to live your life. One is as though nothing is a miracle. The other is as though everything is a miracle.\u201d", "Autor": "Albert Einstein", "Palabras Claves": "inspirational,life,live,miracle,miracles"},
> {"Texto": "\u201cThere are only two ways to live your life. One is as though nothing is a miracle. The other is as though everything is a miracle.\u201d", "Autor": "Albert Einstein", "Palabras Claves": "inspirational,life,live,miracle,miracles"},
> {"Texto": "\u201cIt is better to be hated for what you are than to be loved for what you are not.\u201d", "Autor": "Andr\u00e9 Gide", "Palabras Claves": "life,love"},
> {"Texto": "\u201cThis life is what you make it. No matter what, you're going to mess up sometimes, it's a universal truth. But the good part is you get to decide how you're going to mess it up. Girls will be your friends - they'll act like it anyway. But just remember, some come, some go. The ones that stay with you through everything - they're your true best friends. Don't let go of them. Also remember, sisters make the best friends in the world. As for lovers, well, they'll come and go too. And baby, I hate to say it, most of them - actually pretty much all of them are going to break your heart, but you can't give up because if you give up, you'll never find your soulmate. You'll never find that half who makes you whole and that goes for everything. Just because you fail once, doesn't mean you're gonna fail at everything. Keep trying, hold on, and always, always, always believe in yourself, because if you don't, then who will, sweetie? So keep your head high, keep your chin up, and most importantly, keep smiling, because life's a beautiful thing and there's so much to smile about.\u201d", "Autor": "Marilyn Monroe", "Palabras Claves": "friends,heartbreak,inspirational,life,love,sisters"},
> {"Texto": "\u201cI may not have gone where I intended to go, but I think I have ended up where I needed to be.\u201d", "Autor": "Douglas Adams", "Palabras Claves": "life,navigation"},
> {"Texto": "\u201cGood friends, good books, and a sleepy conscience: this is the ideal life.\u201d", "Autor": "Mark Twain", "Palabras Claves": "books,contentment,friends,friendship,life"},
> {"Texto": "\u201cLife is what happens to us while we are making other plans.\u201d", "Autor": "Allen Saunders", "Palabras Claves": "fate,life,misattributed-john-lennon,planning,plans"},
> {"Texto": "\u201cToday you are You, that is truer than true. There is no one alive who is Youer than You.\u201d", "Autor": "Dr. Seuss", "Palabras Claves": "comedy,life,yourself"},
> {"Texto": "\u201cLife is like riding a bicycle. To keep your balance, you must keep moving.\u201d", "Autor": "Albert Einstein", "Palabras Claves": "life,simile"},
> {"Texto": "\u201cLife isn't about finding your

Se supone que solo son 10 páginas y 10 citas por páginas,dando un total de 100 citas pero mi Spider me exporta 334 citas y hay citas repetidas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personalmente no me gusta usar `LinkExtractor()` o `Rule()` cuando no es absolutamente necesario. Ya que es añadir complicaciones a cosas, que se pueden hacer de forma sencilla en código

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "witsi"
    allowed_domains = ["quotes.toscrape.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        citas = response.xpath('//*[@class="quote"]')
        for cita in quotes:
            text = cita.xpath('.//*[@class="text"]/text()').extract_first()
            author = cita.xpath('.//*[@itemprop="author"]/text()').extract_first()
            tags = cita.xpath('.//*[@itemprop="keywords"]/@content').extract_first()

            yield{'Text': text,
                  'Author': author,
                  'Tags': tags}

        next_page_url = response.xpath('//*[@class="next"]/a/@href').extract_first()
        absolute_next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
        yield scrapy.Request(absolute_next_page_url)
```

### Explicación del código

El código es similar al tuyo

1. He quitado `LinkExtractor()` y `Rule()`
2. En el `for` extraigo con `yield` todos los libros que hay en cada página
3. Cuando ha acabado de extraer los libros, vuelvo a usar un `yield` para hacer la paginación, extrayendo el botón de **next**

De esta forma extraemos todos los libros que hay en todas las páginas.

Comment: ohhhhhhh eres el papu de papuss. Muchas gracias funcionó al 100.

es que había visto otro video y el que vi hablaba de eso (el video si era viejo como 2 años atrás).

y pues el usaba reglas y las otras funciones que quitaste.

gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: De nada! Como eres nuevo probablemente no lo sepas, pero la mejor manera de dar las gracias en StackOverflow es marcando la reapuesta como “Respuesta correcta” y por qué no? Darle una puntuación positiva!

Comment: ya le presione pero dice que soy nuevo y aunque no se vea que vote como correcta me dice que el voto si conto.

cuando le doy votar aparece el 1 y luego se pasa al 0 y me sale el mensaje.

"¡Gracias por tu comentario! Los votos emitidos por quienes tienen menos de 15 de reputación se registran, pero no cambian la puntuación que se muestra públicamente."

Comment: Si no te preocupes, es porque eres nuevo, en el futuro te aparecerán cuando votes! Gracias y me alegro de haberte ayudado

Comment: Hola hola que crees ya pude solucionar tambien de la forma en que lo hice.

el problema estaba en mi regla _allow=r'page/'_

ya que alli me traigo todo lo que tenga page/ y según yo traía esto nada mas _http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/4/_

pero no y si, ya que se traia todo lo que tenga _page/_ y no solamente _http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/4/__http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/5/_ por lo tanto tambien se traia _http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/library/page/1/_ ya que tambien contiene _page/_ y pues cumple con la regla.

y como me di, cuenta. Como soy aferrado (no se si sea bueno o malo)

Comment: en este caso fue bueno jajajaja (llevaba como 3 dias buscando porque ). (aferrado es igual persona terca ).

segui investigando mas y descubri que puedo sacar un Log en txt con las siguientes lineas _-s LOG_FILE=scrapy.log_ a si que eso lo agregue a la hora de exportar mi json y mequedó asi _C:\Users\INFO03\Desktop\segundaArana>scrapy crawl witsi -s LOG_FILE=scrapy.log -
o asdf.json_

entonces entre al log que se hizo y pude ver ese error que todo lo que tuviera _page/_ me lo iba a imprimir. y dije euroka entonces el problema esta en mi regla a si que lo que hice fue, como yo quiero

Comment: que buscará asi _http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/_ y no asi http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/thinking/page/1/ 

a mi regla le puse el _.com_ y asi ya me va atraer todo lo que este asi  _http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/5/_.

y pues gracias al Log y a tu Respuestas para analizar mejor me di cuenta jajajaja. Gracias por tu ayuda

´ Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'.com/page/'),callback = 'parse', follow=True ),'

Comment: ahora ya tengo 2 versiones jijijij